# Eslint : no-unused-vars

Tags: node.js, mongodb, eslint

I am new in using Eslint to fixing the bugs and I have got the following error.

`error  'query' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars`

My code is

```
  const query = Samples.find().where('patientId', patientId).exec((err, docs) => {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    // If no errors, send them back to the client
    res.json({ items: docs });
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is `query` used in other parts of your code?  It's not clear here.

Comment: Well, where do you ever use the `query` variable?  The linter is telling you that you don't use it, and your code seems to agree with that.

Comment: Little can be said from the above code but an issue is already opened in the eslint repo which is reportedly showing false positives.https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12117

Comment: I would have posted the other parts of the code if `query` is used. So this is the first line where I have used `query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `const query` part. Unless they're more code you're not sharing (which you should in order to create a reproducible example), it appears you don't actually need it:

```
Samples.find().where('patientId', patientId).exec((err, docs) => {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    // If no errors, send them back to the client
    res.json({ items: docs });
});
```

Comment: That's the answer. It's a one liner code which I was using. I didn't know that I could have written the query without using const query. New in node :)